# Sequence Alignment with Skips

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, subsequences, bioinformatics

In my thesis I am working on a problem connected with sequence alignment, in particular, I deal with the Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) algorithm (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) for more), which is used to evaluate the distance between two time series. It is very similar to the Needleman–Wunsch algorithm for aligning protein sequences, the difference is: NW finds a maximum score alignment, whereas DTW finds a minimum distance alignment; and DTW does not penalise gaps.

The question I am having is the following one. Given two sequences ***S*** and ***T***, what is the *maximum* DTW distance between them if points along ***S*** can be skipped. I tried adjusting the standard DTW dynamic programming algorithm, but this problem may not be as trivial as it seems. For example, finding the *minimum* DTW distance between ***S*** and ***T*** if points along ***S*** can be skipped is easy, we just need to extend the recurrence relation from the original alignment algorithm; but this trick does not seem to be working with the problem I have.

I would be very grateful for any ideas on how to tackle this problem or any links to relevant literature.

More formally, DTW distance is defined via the following recurrence relation:
$$d_{DTW}(\langle\rangle,\langle\rangle)=0,$$
$$d_{DTW}(S,\langle\rangle)=\infty,$$
$$d_{DTW}(\langle\rangle,T)=\infty,$$
$$d_{DTW}(S,T)=\delta(S_n,T_m)+\min\{d_{DTW}(S_{1:n-1},T_{1:m-1}),d_{DTW}(S_{1:n-1},T_{1:m}),d_{DTW}(S_{1:n},T_{1:m-1})\},$$
where $\delta$ is the local distance function (usually $L_1$ or $L_2$ metric) and $|S|=n$ and $|T|=m$. What I am looking for is a subsequence $S'$ of $S$, such that is $$\arg\max_{S'}d_{DTW}(S',T).$$